# How delete all rows that contain a certain value regardless of what column it is in

Tags: r, subset, apply

I need to delete all rows that contain a value of 2 or -2 regardless of what column it is in except column one.

Example dataframe:

df

```
  a    b    c    d
zzz    2    2   -1
yyy    1    1    1
xxx    1   -1   -2
```

Desired output:

df

```
  a    b    c    d
yyy    1    1    1
```

I have tried

`df <- df[!grepl(-2 | 2, df),]`

`df <- subset(df, !df[-1] == 2 |!df[-1] == -2)`

My actual dataset has over 300 rows and 70 variables

I believe I need to use some sort of `apply` function but I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a logical index by comparing the absolute value of the dataset with that of 2, get the row wise sum and if there are no values, it will be 0 (by negating `!`, it returns TRUE for those 0 values and FALSE for others) and subset based on the logical index

```
df[!rowSums(abs(df[-1])==2),]
#   a b c d
#2 yyy 1 1 1
```

---

Or another option is to compare within each column using `lapply`, collapse it to a logical vector with `|` and use that to subset the rows

```
df[!Reduce(`|`,lapply(abs(df[-1]), `==`, 2)),]
#    a b c d
#2 yyy 1 1 1
```

---

We could also do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    select(-1) %>% #to remove the first column
    map(~abs(.) ==2) %>% #do the columnwise comparison
    reduce(`|`) %>% #reduce it to logical vector
    `!` %>%  #negate to convert TRUE/FALSE to FALSE/TRUE
     df[., ] #subset the rows of original dataset
#     a b c d
# 2 yyy 1 1 1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("zzz", "yyy", "xxx"), b = c(2L, 1L, 1L), 
c = c(2L, 1L, -1L), d = c(-1L, 1L, -2L)), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Changing `d` to `df` in your lappy answer worked perfectly.

Comment: The rowSums solutions can also work for a variable number of columns by changing to `df[rowSums(!abs(df[-1]) == 2) == ncol(df)-1, ]`

Answer (score 0):

Option with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
a <- c("zzz","yyy","xxx")
b <- c(2,1,1)
c <- c(2,1,-1)
d <- c(-1,1,-2)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

filter(df,((abs(b) != 2) & (abs(c) != 2) & (abs(d) != 2)))

    a b c d
1 yyy 1 1 1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I believe your solution would work but I have over 70 variables which makes listing every variable in the `filter` function time-consuming.